# Bowser message: Wordpress HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: wordpress

I get this error on access my site. 500 error in browser.
in debug mode i get this fatal error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wp_getElementByCSS() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php:5643) in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5706
```

how do i fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is fixed, would you add a solution below please? We don't edit answers or [solved] messages into questions here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fix: renamed the wp-content/plugins folder to i.e. "plugins--", created new empty plugins folder in the same directory, renamed the active theme folder, Replaced all wp files  with the running version of wp.